# Uninstall windows VM installed with curl on Mac

Tags: macos, curl, virtualbox

I tried installing a Windows VM with IE11 using the curl command

```
curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | IEVMS_VERSIONS=”11″ bash
```

This didn't end up being recognised as a VM on Oracle Virtual box, so I headed over to windows' website and downloaded a zip folder which worked fine. I'm looking for a way to uninstall/remove the previously installed windows VM (It is verifiably taking up space) that I installed using cURL on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the file like this:

```
find / -type f -name "*.exe"
```

You can also search for zip because I see zip files in that `.sh`:

```
find / -type f -name "*.zip"
```

If you have a lot of zip files you should search for every image like:

```
find / -name "IE9_Win7.zip"
```